# "take them away to sell" or "take them away to be sold"?

Tags: active-vs-passive

> The hunters took them away to [ sell / be sold].

Why are one thing active voice and the other passive voice, when they mean the same thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, there is rarely only one way to say something. Learners shouldn't be too confused if there is more than one valid way to express a thought or concept.

In this case, though, I don't agree that they necessarily mean precisely the same thing. When we say:

> The hunters took them away to sell.

that implies the hunters will be doing the selling. However, when we say:

> They hunters took them away to be sold.

that can mean that some other vendor will be doing the selling, not the hunters themselves. (Perhaps the hunters will bring them to a butcher shop, and butcher will start selling them tomorrow.) In a situation like that one, I think the passive voice works better, because it doesn't create the false impression that the hunters themselves will be selling things to customers.